# <a4j:mediaoutput , loads images slowly? what can be the reason?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am inspecting a portal's page for loading of images ,its loading very slow.
We pick images from a filesystem , images name from database and read them, create a list  and show results using  a4j:mediaOutput   tag. but the images are being loaded very slowly.

http://www.easyrenting.com/list-detail/3bhk-ardee-city-sector-52/6263

Comment: I have added a link, simillar problem i am facing and trying to resolve .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I see is that all your pictures are high-res (1800px x 2400px).

You really should create thumbnails server side to meet your view requirement and load images according of the size you want to show on the client size.

Have you only verified that your web page weight about **6.5MB** including all images? (Check with Firebug).

I would recommand you a custom servlet like this one [FileServlet supporting resume and caching with GZIP](http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html), and create a URL pattern according to load full res or thumbnail depending of the requirement.

Comment: thanks alexandre, i too observed the same reasons at primary stage, but i am in confusion mode , how to get it solved.

Comment: @durgesh First thing I would ask is : how are stored your images?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem using the a4j:mediaOutput tag.
The images are getting loaded slowly because the size is too large, you need to find out a way to optimize the image size. Probably you can re-size the images before saving it to your file system.
Unless you are giving the zoom functionality, you do not need these big images.

That should help!

Comment: You can check the size of your web page using firebug as suggested by Alex. 

The following link should tell you how to do that:
https://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: Hi Aditya, thanks for your valuable commented , i used it before too , it really works.